# What is the difference between P(W1,W2) vs P(W2|W1) in this context

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, decision-trees

What is the conceptual difference between the probability of winning two successive games in a playoff series vs winning the second game given that you won the first game?

I understand P(W2|W1) as the probability of winning the second game given you've won the first game, but I can't see how to interpret P(W2, W1), or if it even applies in this context; I think to get to W2 you have to have W1 as a given.

I can find similar examples [here](https://www.quora.com/In-probability-whats-the-difference-between-P-A-and-B-and-P-A-given-B) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43623/what-is-the-difference-between-pa-b-and-pab) but they lack the successive nature of a series of games.

I've mapped out my cases as tree of possibilities to try to see how P(W2, W1) would fit in. Is there a better way to think about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf P(W_1,W_2)$ is the *joint probability* of the events; that is the probability of their intersection, also written as $\mathsf P(W_1\cap W_2)$. The probability that both events have occurred (win game 1 and game 2).

$\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)$ is the *conditional probability* that $W_2$ occurs when it is given that $W_1$ has.

By the definition for conditional probability, we have that:

$$\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(W_1, W_2)}{\mathsf P(W_1)}$$

Or $\mathsf P(W_1,W_2)=\mathsf P(W_1)\cdot \mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)$

Comment: Thanks - but what is the conceptual meaning of this joint probability? How can I have the probability of W1 and W2 be different from W2 given W1, in this particular case. I can't win game 2 unless I've won game 1. That's what I'm having a hard time with.

Comment: The joint probability is the measure of expectation that both events will occur.  Hence it is the probability that the second event will occur *under condition* that the first event does, *multiplied by* the probability that the first event will in fact occur.

Comment: The probability for winning the second game *if* the first game has been won is $\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)$.  The probability that the first game has been won is $\mathsf P(W_1)$.  Thus the probability that both games are won, $\mathsf P(W_1, W_2)$ is calculated as: $$\mathsf P(W_1, W_2)~=~\mathsf P(W_2\mid W_1)\times\mathsf P(W_1)$$

Comment: Thanks again. For some reason your last comment helped to clear things up, even though you had similarly stated it in the math notation.